# Unmarshall JSON body from top level element

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

There are already too many similar questions like this but here's one more take on it:

I have a problem where my Ajax post (PUT) from a react component is being wrapped in a containing "parent" element. The data being sent over the wire is this:

```
{"person":{"id":"1b982e30-c6b3-4297-dd02-08d4a8d9346a","firstname":"Phil","lastname":"Wheeler","email":"phil@email","phone":"55521234","birthdate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","workplace":null,"hobbies":null,"other":null,"occupations":null}}
```

The API method is pretty simple:

```
[HttpPut("{id}")]
public void Put(Guid id, [FromBody]Client person)
{
    // Do the stuff
}
```

The `Client` model is just a simple class.

If I'm posting the JSON data as above, the properties are all null. If we remove the parent "person" element (i.e. 'unmarshalling' the JSON request), everything works just fine.

So I have a couple of options: I can change my API method to accept a type of "dynamic" instead of the strongly-typed "Client" object; I can wrap my "Client" class and accept that object instead:

```
public class Request
{
    public Client person { get; set; }
}
```

Or I can figure out a way to unbundle the Ajax call from my script. Currently it's this:

```
axios.put(this.props.url + '/' + value.id, { value } )
    .then(results => {
        console.info("Do some stuff");
    });
```

My preference is to have strongly-typed objects on my API methods because I feel it's more legible and obvious that way, but I'm not *that* wedded to it. Is there something obvious I'm missing, or should I just take the path of least resistance and change my code to fit the data?

Comment: So it all comes down to the origin of `value`. Where's the code that populates that object?

Comment: @CodeCaster That's one line up in my React code: it's just picking up an object from state: `        var value = this.state.selectedPerson;`

Comment: Then my question moves one line up: where does `this.state.selectedPerson` come from? It's React that's wrapping your object, so relevant code would be that React code. Or just put `value.person`?

Comment: Ok, depending on how far back we want to move, the state is populated with the person class properties based on a drop-down the user selects. That drop down populates based on an Ajax GET request. The array of "person" objects returned is essentially dropped onto the state of a parent class. So the types and number of properties in each case remains constant; only the values are updated.

Comment: Why not use `axios.put(this.props.url + '/' + value.id, value )`